# How to instantiate a class T<U> inside a method

Tags: c#, generics, instantiation

This one has to do with generics in c#.

I have a class that needs to create instances of another class T that is itself generic.
How can I do it? Really scratching my mind and my generics experience is limited.

The class that needs to create those instances is declared as:

```
public TCPSmartServer<T , U> : IDisposable where T : FrameWrapperBase<U>, new()
{
    private CreateFrameWrapper()
    {
        T<U> frameWrapper = new T<U>();
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it:

```
T frameWrapper = new T();
```

A test example seems to work. Will report back with the full scale soft.